# Cannot manage backlog using Visual Studio Online

Tags: agile, azure-devops, backlog

I appreciate that this is a moving target, however.
I have attempted to manage my VSO backlog using both the Drag and Drop functionality and the Stack Rank Approach. On 2015 09 25 i noted along with a coworker that either manner resulted in sparcification which did not leave the backlog in the same order in which i had placed it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/14/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

The issue from MSDN does not indicate that this is designed behavior however when my backlog is consistently 300 items having a random order applied to my backlog causes havoc on a daily basis. In fact i was fairly certain it was sabotage.

1. Has anyone else noted this.
2. is there a way to over come this issue.
   Links or other guidance will be truly appreciated

I have used both Excel and the "edit work item" feature to change the stack  rank.

what i have observed is this

Lets say i have only 5 items in my backlog ( i actually have 300)+

I set the stack rank of the first 3 items to be equal so thay clump together

#### work item |stackrank| Order

1. | 1 | 1
2. | 1 | 2
3. | 1 | 3
4. | 2 | 4
5. | 9 | 5

For 5 minutes that is the order i see on the webpage ( if i was not clear my VSO is hosted on Azure)

After a certain time ( it happens almost immediately) the sparcification does this ( NOTE order as well as stackrank) *keeping number sane on purpose althougt i know that MS uses much larger ordination

#### work item |stackrank| Order

3. | 1 | 1
4. | 3 | 2
5. | 5 | 3
6. | 7 | 4
7. | 9 | 5

So why does it not respect my clumping strategy?

I have been watching the backlog with a skeptical eye for the last week and it is appears to be reordering items without human intervention.I cannot be completely certain , however i am the backlog owner and 99% of the time ppl fess up when they add items without prior conversation. ( it happens in my organization and wont be stopped *shrug*)

Comment: Are you (or is anyone else) using Excel to manage the backlog?

Comment: My comments are too long posted in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the Stack Rank field is removed from work item form. Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/07/08/where-is-the-field-on-the-work-item-form-to-order-the-backlog.aspx) for the details.

Secondly, just as Daniel mentioned above, you can use Excel to order the backlog as the field is still part of the work item, it is only removed from the form.